# How to change Font size

Tags: formatting, fonts

Please tell me please how can I change the font size globally. I tried through Option Inspector-> FontOptions-> Font size. Global Preferences parameter changed, but the font in notepad is not[image: FontSize for text in notebook]
[image: FontSize Globally]